# How Can i add jquery code in single wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a script that requires jQuery, and I don't know how to add it into a single wordress page.
I looked for many solution, but they are too hard for me to understand.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#checkboxtest').change(function(){
    if( $('#checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = "YES";}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = "NO";}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
        })
        
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Alongside the answers provided below you should use an `enqueue_script()` to retrieve the jquery from a separate file as per the wordpress codex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all - you should rewrite your jQuery wrapper for code to work within WP pages:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#checkboxtest').change(function(){
        if( $('#checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
           {checkboxstatus = "YES";}
           else
           {checkboxstatus = "NO";}
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
            data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
            })
            
    });
});
```

Now you can add this code to a Wordpress page in two ways:

**Using a plugin for custom code snippets (like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/))**

Or if your page is using a custom-coded template, you can directly paste the

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

tag with your code, where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php if (is_page('my-page-slug')): ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#checkboxtest').change(function(){
    if( $('#checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = "YES";}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = "NO";}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
        })
});
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to add javascript to your WordPress.

The easiest way is to use plugins like this one [css javascript toolbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/) to add your scripts where you need on your WordPress.

Another way is to update your WordPress template and insert your code where it needed. This link provide you a full example of how achieved this: [add-javascript-to-wordpress](https://www.collectiveray.com/add-javascript-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Use code like below:

```
  <?php
    function myscript() {
        // if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        // if ( is_singular( 'book' ) ) {  // book is a custom post type 
        if ( is_single()) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Hello! I am Added");
    
            </script>
        <?php
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'myscript');
```

Another example:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    // if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
    // if ( is_singular( 'book' ) ) {  // book is a custom post type 
    if ( is_single()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```